# sum of elements inside python list

Tags: python, list, sum

I'm trying to write some code that can sum elements inside a list that looks like the following example:

```
list[(a,b,1),(c,d,2),(e,f,3)]
```

What I want to do is to sum the numbers inside this list. What is the name of such kind of lists?

Hope you can help me.

Comment: It's a nested list (the nested elements are tuples in this case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a list, and assuming you have to sum integers as given in the example

```
foo = [('a','b',1),('c','d',2),('e','f',3)]
```

You can do the following

```
sum(e for e in itertools.chain(*foo) if isinstance(e, int))
```

- Here [itertools.chain](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) would flatten the list
- [isinstance](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) checks if the element is an instance of integer
- sum only those elements which is an instance of int

Incase if the number elements are at a defined index, as in the example, you can do

```
>>> zip(*foo)
[('a', 'c', 'e'), ('b', 'd', 'f'), (1, 2, 3)]
>>> sum(zip(*foo)[2])
6
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

it's a list of tuples, you need to iterate over individual elements of the list and extract the value, once extracted you can `sum` on them

```
In [103]: l = [('a','b',1),('c','d',2),('e','f',3)]

In [104]: sum([x[2] for x in l])
Out[104]: 6
```

Comment: if list structure is consistent in pattern (for index of integer in tuple), then this solution is faster.

Answer (score 0):

you can use func flatten() to parse a nested list like followed list
    lst = [('a', 'b' , (1,  2)), ('c', 'd' , 2), ('e', 'f', 3)]

```
def flatten(l):  
    for el in l:  
        if hasattr(el, "__iter__") and not isinstance(el, basestring):  
            for sub in flatten(el):  
                yield sub  
        else:  
            yield el 

print sum(e for e in flatten(lst) if isinstance(e, int))
```

Answer (score 0):

Reducing an iterable to a single value is what the built-in [reduce](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) function was created for:

```
In [1]: l = [("a", "b", 1), ("c", "d", 2), ("e", "f", 3)]

In [2]: reduce(lambda x,y: x + y[2], l, 0)
Out[2]: 6
```

So you don't need to iterate explicitly, the `reduce` function does it for you. Neither you need to import additional modules.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [('a','b',1),('c','d',2),('e','f',3)]

my_answer = sum(z for x,y,z in my_list)
```

nice and concise, and very readable for future you. There is no question what is going in here.